How to deal with Futurewarning regarding applying Inplace method in pandas
I am trying to replace blank values in a column  with nan and then drop the blank rows of that column with the following code. but getting an error.
code:
df['CellNRARFCN'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)

df1 = df.dropna(subset=['CellNRARFCN'], inplace=True)

error message:

py:14: FutureWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a DataFrame or Series through chained assignment using an inplace method.
The behavior will change in pandas 3.0. This inplace method will never work because the intermediate object on which we are setting values always behaves as a copy.
For example, when doing 'df[col].method(value, inplace=True)', try using 'df.method({col: value}, inplace=True)' or df[col] = df[col].method(value) instead, to perform the operation inplace on the original object.

Can anyone suggest how I can get the code modified so I do not get the warning?

There are suggestions right there in the warning message, have you tried them? What did you try and what was the result? df[col] = df[col].method(value) looks good.

Also, df1 will be None with this code, since with inplace=True, a method has nothing to return.

You can try below.
Read this answer in SO where it mentions

inplace=True at the end of the chain does not modify the original
dataframe.

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample data
data = {
    'CellNRARFCN': ['100', '', '200', np.nan, '300', '']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print("Original DataFrame:")
print(df)

# Replace blank strings with np.nan
df['CellNRARFCN'] = df['CellNRARFCN'].replace('', np.nan)

# Drop rows where 'CellNRARFCN' is NaN
df = df.dropna(subset=['CellNRARFCN'])

print("\nUpdated DataFrame (after replacing and dropping NaN rows):")
print(df)

Original DataFrame:
  CellNRARFCN
0         100
1            
2         200
3         NaN
4         300
5 

Updated DataFrame (after replacing and dropping NaN rows):
  CellNRARFCN
0         100
2         200
4         300


Thanks for letting me know and glad it worked for you :) if it is helpful you can upvote and accept as answer :)
